# Searching for a Value in a HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a HashMap of the following type: `HashMap<LocalDate, ArrayList<String>>` which contains values like:

```
2015-12-26=[John, J.Fox , Barry]
2015-12-24=[Barry, Michael, Martin],
2015-12-20=[McAllister, Barry, Clark]
..............
```

Now, if I want to search for `"Barry"` in the `HashMap` and get the key which is the most recent (in this case Dec 26th), how would I go about doing that?

The `.values()` method doesn't seem to work as each key has an `ArrayList` instead of just one element.

Comment: Why didn't you write an iterator?

Comment: I am fairly new to Java. So, i am not exactly sure how to use an iterator here for this. Can you give me some pointers on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java 8 you could use something like this:

```
Optional<Map.Entry<LocalDate, List<String>>> first = map
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains("Barry"))
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .findFirst();
```

This get all the entries from the map, filters them based on the value, sort them based on keys and get the first one, if any. You can then use `first.ifPresent()` method to do whatever you want with the first entry, here i just printing them to the console:

```
first.ifPresent(entry -> {
            System.out.println(entry);
        });
```

Maybe this is **NOT** the most efficient algorithm but sure it works

**Update 1:** To sort dates from latest to earliest, use this:

```
sorted(Map.Entry.<LocalDate, List<String>>comparingByKey().reversed())
```

**Update 2:** As Andreas said, you can use `max` instead of `sorted` which has better asymptotic behavior. In fact, since you just want the latest item, there is no need for sorting entries in order to get it:

```
Optional<Map.Entry<LocalDate, List<String>>> found = map
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains("Barry"))
                .max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey());
```

Comment: explanation please. if he's new to java, then streams are probably not part of his vocab yet.

Comment: A `Map<K,V>` can be seen as a `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>`. The code streams that set, picking all entries with value "Barry" (that's the filter call with the lambda function). Then it asks the results to be sorted according to the natural ordering of Map.Entry, and picks the first every according to that ordering. I don't think this pipeline would work since Map.Entry does not implement Comparable. You might want to use `.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())` instead.

Comment: Thanks javier for explanation

Comment: Lambda expressions. Nice.

Comment: the `sorted()` method is ordering them in an increasing order. But, i want in the descending order. I couldn't find any proper answer to reversing a stream..

Comment: `sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey((k1, k2) -> k2.compareTo(k1)))`

Comment: Basically it compares second key with the first one and sort them descending

Comment: Or more elegantly, `Map.Entry.<LocalDate, List<String>>comparingByKey().reversed()`

Comment: Thanks @AliDehghani I have learnt a lot about using Streams just from this answer.

Comment: Wouldn't `max(comparator)` perform much better than `sorted(comparator).findFirst()`? Fewer comparisons: `n - 1` vs. `n * log(n)` (probably).

Answer (score 3):

Use the map's `Entry Set`. For example:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

list1.add("One");
list1.add("Two");
list1.add("Three");

list2.add("Cat");
list2.add("Dog");
list2.add("Fish");

map.put("Numbers", list1);
map.put("Animals", list2);

for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    if(entry.getValue().contains("Cat"))
        System.out.println("Found Cat in "+entry.getKey());
}
```

Output: `Found Cat in Animals`

Essentially, what we are doing is *iterating* over the map's `Entry Set`, checking if each `value` (which we specified is an `ArrayList<String>`) contains the `String` we are looking for, and if it does, we print out the `key` of the current `Entry`. (Which, in your case, would be your `LocalDate`.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to find the key while searching for a value, you need to use `entrySet()`.

Given that your keys are dates, and hence have a natural order, and you want latest matching date, you have 3 choices:

- Keep the `HashMap`, search *entire list*, and remember largest key value.
- Change to `TreeMap`, search backwards using `descendingMap()`, and stop on first hit.
- Change to reverse-order `TreeMap`, search, and stop on first hit.

If your list is huge and/or you do the search a lot, a `TreeMap` is preferable, for performance reasons.

Since it is unclear whether `LocalDate` is from Java 8 or from Joda-Time, the following code uses `compareTo`, which is implemented by both. Code doesn't use Java 8 specific features.

Here are the 3 versions:

```java
// HashMap
HashMap<LocalDate, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
...
LocalDate matchedKey = null;
for (Entry<LocalDate, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
    if (entry.getValue().contains(valueToFind))
        if (matchedKey == null || entry.getKey().compareTo(matchedKey) > 0)
            matchedKey = entry.getKey();
```

```java
// TreeMap (descending search)
TreeMap<LocalDate, ArrayList<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
...
LocalDate matchedKey = null;
for (Entry<LocalDate, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.descendingMap().entrySet())
    if (entry.getValue().contains(valueToFind)) {
        matchedKey = entry.getKey();
        break;
    }
```

```java
// TreeMap (reverse-order)
TreeMap<LocalDate, ArrayList<String>> map = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder()); // or Comparator.reverseOrder() in Java 8
...
LocalDate matchedKey = null;
for (Entry<LocalDate, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
    if (entry.getValue().contains(valueToFind)) {
        matchedKey = entry.getKey();
        break;
    }
```

Of course, in Java 8, these can also be done using streams and Lambdas.